# How can I write proper benchmarks for measure rendering performance of fyne canvas objects in Go?

Tags: performance, go, fyne

In my application I need render full-white image but I want to render that image with good performance. The fyne library I used to render images is giving me more than one option to render the image. Hence I have decided to write benchmarks for them to check which one has good performance over other. But I couldn't figure out how to write proper benchmark for those. The fyne library have test package for those things. So I have tried this:

```
package main

import (
    "image"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/test"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
    "testing"
)

var im = image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0,0, 3000, 4000))

func BenchmarkRaster(b *testing.B) {
    for i,_  := range im.Pix{
        im.Pix[i] = 255
    }
    
    d := canvas.NewRasterFromImage(im)
    
    d.ScaleMode = canvas.ImageScaleFastest
    
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        test.NewWindow(d)
    }
}

func BenchmarkImage(b *testing.B) {

    for i,_  := range im.Pix{
        im.Pix[i] = 255
    }

    d := canvas.NewImageFromImage(im)
    
    d.ScaleMode = canvas.ImageScaleFastest
    
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        test.NewWindow(d)
    }

}
```

This benchmark for making and register a new window with a canvas object. But I am not sure it is for my purpose.
I have two questions:
Is benchmark that I wrote upper okay for measure rendering performance ?
If not how can I write proper benchmark for measure rendering performance ?
*Note:* With rendering I mean showing an image always on window. I need measure its performance.

Answer (score 0):

To get real graphical performance you need to run an app. This is how it hooks up to OpenGL and the graphics acceleration. The benchmark and unit testing works well, but it is loading a software driver for the purpose - so you won’t get high graphical performance.

I think that means you’ll need to display in a window, and do the timing yourself - from a regular main function.

Comment: It looks like I will do it with that way. I only was curious if there is a writing benchamark way for it.

Comment: A question. I benchmarked two objects with loading software driver, and I see first object faster than second object. Then even in the real graphics performance, will be same means object1 faster than object2 ? Or in the real graphics performance can it change ? If it is same for both. I can do my benchmarks based on loading software driver.

Comment: There is no way to answer that question simply - it will depend hugely on what the objects are, how much rendering they require etc. The software and hardware accelerated drivers share no performance characteristics. The only thing we promise is that they look the same.

Comment: Thank you, until I find better solution, I will use loading software driver for my benchmarks.

Comment: As I said above the software driver will not give you meaningful benchmarks for graphical performance as it cannot use hardware acceleration.

Comment: I understand that, only for see which one is good at software accelaration, also I have learned real (not test package) `w.Show()` working on benchmark loop, can I use `w.Show()` for get a bit more accurate for benchmark ? The real `w.Show()`, using hardware acceleration ? I don't need get %100 accurate performance even learning only first time rendering performance is okay for my application.

Comment: It depends on what driver created the window that is being shown. If it appears on screen you are likely benchmarking real performance. Of course the test package is designed to run without the UI show, for fast test performance but not realistic benchmarking.